# Rerender Pageblocksection with a rich text field

Tags: apex, visualforce, rerender, pageblocksection, richtext-notes

I have requirement to rerender a pageblock section when I click the "Add Note" button. But the challenge here is I am unable to rerender the rich
text field `<apex:inputField value="{!rec.rawNoteItem.Notes__c}"/>` which is rich text field. I get an error on VF page saying - `Rerender is not currently supported with rich text editing enabled`  On some further reading I found that rerender is not supported
for rich text field. Below is my code:

```
                   <apex:pageBlockSection id="pbsNotes" collapsible="true" columns="1" showHeader="true" title="Notes">
                        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="pbsNotes1">
                            <apex:outputPanel id="pnlNotes">
                                <apex:commandButton value="Add Note" action="{!addNoteRows}" reRender="pbsNotes"/>
                            </apex:outputPanel>
                        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="pbsNotes2"> 
                           <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!noteLines}" var="rec">
                               <apex:column style="width:10%;padding-right:5%;padding-bottom:10%">
                                   <apex:commandLink value="Delete Note" action="{!deleteNoteItem}">
                                       <apex:param name="selectedComparisonIndex" value="{!rec.Index}"/>
                                       <u style="cursor: pointer"></u>
                                   </apex:commandLink>
                               </apex:column>
                               <apex:column style="width:25%;padding-bottom:10%" headerValue="Title">
                                   <apex:inputText value="{!rec.rawNoteItem.Title__c}" size="50"/>
                               </apex:column>
                               <apex:column style="width:50%;padding-right:10%" headerValue="Note">
                                   <apex:inputField value="{!rec.rawNoteItem.Notes__c}"/>
                               </apex:column>
                             </apex:pageBlockTable>
                         </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                </apex:pageBlock>
```

What I tried to do - I tried to put the pageblock section in outputPanel tags and tried to rerender the outputPanel when the 'Add Note' button is clicked. But I get an error in the page for this - `Rerender is not currently supported with rich text editing enabled`

```
                    <apex:outputPanel id="pnlN">
                    <apex:pageBlockSection id="pbsNotes" collapsible="true" columns="1" showHeader="true" title="Notes">
                        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="pbsNotes1">
                            <apex:outputPanel id="pnlNotes">
                                <apex:commandButton value="Add Note" action="{!addNoteRows}" reRender="pnlN"/>
                            </apex:outputPanel>
                        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="pbsNotes2"> 
                           <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!noteLines}" var="rec">
                               <apex:column style="width:10%;padding-right:5%;padding-bottom:10%">
                                   <apex:commandLink value="Delete Note" action="{!deleteNoteItem}">
                                       <apex:param name="selectedComparisonIndex" value="{!rec.Index}"/>
                                       <u style="cursor: pointer"></u>
                                   </apex:commandLink>
                               </apex:column>
                               <apex:column style="width:25%;padding-bottom:10%" headerValue="Title">
                                   <apex:inputText value="{!rec.rawNoteItem.Title__c}" size="50"/>
                               </apex:column>
                               <apex:column style="width:50%;padding-right:10%" headerValue="Note">
                                   <apex:inputField value="{!rec.rawNoteItem.Notes__c}"/>
                               </apex:column>
                             </apex:pageBlockTable>
                         </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlock>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please include all error messages *verbatim*.

Comment: Exact error message - Rerender is not currently supported with rich text editing enabled

Comment: To my knowledge, it's not possible using an `apex:inputField` as in your example. I was able to workaround this by rendering the field as a textarea and using JS to instantiate the CKEDITOR. Similar to what's being done here: https://andrewbcummings.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/salesforce-richtext-fail-rerender-is-not-currently-supported-with-rich-text-editing-enabled/

Comment: @AntonioManente thanks! I guess is this the only way? Can it be done using Jquery?

Comment: @SfdcBat Through my research this is the only workaround I found that worked well. I did use jQuery in my implementation as well.

Comment: @SfdcBat I whipped up an example using jQuery in my answer

Comment: @AntonioManente Thanks for throwing out ideas to get me started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick barebones example of what I did to workaround this issue. There is a separate VF component I include in the page to help handle the rich text fields:

```
<apex:component >
    // include my own resource for the CKEDITOR script
    <apex:includescript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.CKEditor, 'ckeditor/ckeditor.js')}" />

    <script>
        // By default, replaceAll runs on ALL textarea fields. 
        // modified to run only on the class defined 'ckeditor'
        CKEDITOR.replaceAll = function(){for(var a=document.getElementsByClassName("ckeditor"),b=0;b<a.length;b++){var d=null,k=a[b];if(k.name||k.id){if("string"==typeof arguments[0]){if(!(new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)"+arguments[0]+"(?:$|\\s)")).test(k.className))continue}else if("function"==typeof arguments[0]&&(d={},!1===arguments[0](k,d)))continue;this.replace(k,d)}}};

        // destroys and rebuilds the rich text fields after rerender
        function afterRerenderRTF() {
           for(name in CKEDITOR.instances){
                delete CKEDITOR.instances[name];
           }

           CKEDITOR.replaceAll();
        }

        // I use this before save as I've observed situations where changes are lost, 
        // particularly after the fields have already been rerendered. 
        // More of a safeguard than anything
        function ensureRichTextContent(){
            $('.ckeditor').each(function(index, el){
                var id = $(el).attr('id') || $(el).attr('name');
                var data = CKEDITOR.instances[id].getData().trim();

                if(CKEDITOR.instances[id].checkDirty())
                    $(el).text(data);
            });
        }
    </script>
</apex:component>
```

Here's a quick example of the page, this can be done without jQuery as well:

```
<apex:page controller='SomeController'>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery, '/js/jquery.js')}"/>
    <c:RerenderRichText/>

    <apex:form id='frm'>
        <apex:inputTextarea styleClass='ckeditor'/>
        <apex:commandButton onclick="ensureRichTextContent();" action="{!doSomethingHere}" oncomplete="afterRerenderRTF();" reRender="frm" value="Submit"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

This method should allow you to rerender rich text fields. At times there could be a noticeable delay as the rich text widgets are built on page load/post rerender, but this has worked quite well for me. You may experience other issues with this as this workaround is definitely unsupported but I hope this helps!